# Setup SoftKeyBoard Cordova Plugin

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, phonegap-plugins, android-softkeyboard

I would like to hide the softkeyboard onBlur.

Therefore, I found the [softkeyboard plugin](https://github.com/nikhilben/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SoftKeyboard), and I suppose I installed it properly, following numerous threads posts.

However, this is the first time I use a plugin for cordova, and I get this error, so I guess something is missing:

`Cannot read property 'SoftKeyBoard' of undefined`

This refers to the js call in the html file:

```
var softkeyboard = window.cordova.plugins.SoftKeyBoard;
$('#keyboard').toggle(softkeyboard.show, softkeyboard.hide);
```

Does not `window.cordova.plugins` exist?

In order to set up the plugin, I did the following:

- copy `SoftKeyBoard.java` to `src/org.apache.cordova.plugins.SoftKeyBoard`. I also rewrote the first line `package` accordingly.
- copy the js file, and link it to the html file
- add this line to `res/xml/config.xml`:

  ```
  <plugin name="SoftKeyBoard" value="org.apache.cordova.plugins.SoftKeyBoard" />
  ```

  In this XML, it's located in `<cordova><plugins>`

Is there anything else I should have done?

Comment: I had the same problem with that plugin, but could not resolve it.  Found a different version though that is newer, https://github.com/originalgremlin/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SoftKeyboard though I've not managed to get this one working yet (issue this time appears to be in the java side of things rather than the js), maybe you'll have more luck

Comment: I am facing same Issue, any luck on your side guys?

Comment: can you post full .java and .js of the plugin and your version of cordova(or just git link)

Comment: also you have to copy .java on src/org/apache/cordova/plugins/SoftKeyBoard
by create directories, and then rebuild